# Open cones in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-cone

Is any proper open cone in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of the form $$C(x, e, \alpha) = \left\{ y\in\mathbb{R}^n : \arccos \frac{e\cdot(y-x)}{|y-x|} < \alpha\right\}$$ for unit vector $e$, angle $0<\alpha<\pi$ and vertex $x$, and uniquely represented by those $3$ values?

I'm asking this for further reference as well as to understand cones.

Edit: I realize now there are other types of open convex cones, so to make the question more meaningful I'm changing my question a little bit.

If $C_0$ is a non-empty open convex cone, does there always exist $C(x, e, \alpha)\subseteq C_0$?

Comment: These will produce circular cones. A cone with any other shape base will not be expressible in this form (e.g. polyhedral cones). But, for cones of this form, this representation will be unique.

Comment: My bad, you're right

Comment: Since $C_0$ is non-empty, there is some $x_0 \in C_0$. Since $C_0$ is open, there is some $r > 0$ such that the open sphere $B_r(x_0)$ of radius $r$ about $x_0$ is entirely contained in $C_0$. Since $C_0$ is a cone, it has a vertex $x$. And since $C_0$ is open, $x \notin C_0$ and therefore $x \ne x_0$.
Let $$e = \frac {x_0 - x}{|x_0 - x|}$$$$\alpha = \arctan \frac r{|x_0 - x|}$$
Then $C(x,e,\alpha) \subseteq C_0$.